# Damaging AT-ATs on Hoth

Tags: star-wars-battlefront-2015

Do the AT-ATs, once their shields are taken down, take part-based damage?

If I shoot the head or neck, will I inflict more damage than if I shoot the body? Or do all parts take hits equally?

Comment: It's difficult to say, conclusively (which is why I'm not directly providing an answer), but my friend and I were partners, and we tried body vs head vs leg shots, and they seemed to do the same amount of damage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a weak spot, on the underbelly of the AT-AT. But just the very narrow cylinder going along the center underside of it. You pretty much have to be standing right underneath it to hit it.

The safer option is probably to stock up on Ion Grenades, Ion Torpedoes, and Ion Shots. Or go for the difficult but quick T-47 take down.

[image: from http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2015-11-13-its-now-easier-for-the-rebels-to-win-in-star-wars-battlefronts-walker-assault-mode]

(Note: This was a [change from the beta](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2015-11-13-its-now-easier-for-the-rebels-to-win-in-star-wars-battlefronts-walker-assault-mode), when it did not have a weak spot.)

Comment: So, the legs, neck, and body all take the same amount of damage then?

Comment: @DCShannon Correct.

Answer (score 0):

Ion shot T-21, T-21B, Disruptor Rifle, DLT-19X, and Pulse Cannon at the neck or underbelly will do a lot of damage. The higher the score you get, the more damage you have done.

Answer (score -1):

Whenever I played it seemed as if there were no differences. However, this could be due to the fact that you cannot really scale your damage by just shooting it as the game converts it into points rather than damage points.

Originally I thought there was a difference but after shooting the head, the back, the underbelly, the legs and anywhere else on the AT-AT I assumed that the game does not have that mechanic yet, or the mechanics will not be implemented.

Hopefully this helped a little.

Comment: I don't think this is true, I seem to be able to do more dps to the legs than the upper body part of the AT-AT.